# Getting camera image from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I am using opencv library to obtain video from the built-in webcam. The following code works perfectly well when i put camera logic code into the main function, but it doesn't when i put it into separate thread. The `task1()` thread stops at `cv::VideoCapture capture(0)`. Meanwhile both `task2()` and the main thread are executing correctly.

Could someone explain me why opencv logic doesn't work when put into separate thread?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

void task1 (){
            cout<<"1st thread ";
            cv::Mat frame;
            cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
            if ( capture.isOpened() == false )
            {
                cout<<"Failed to open camera";
            }

            cv::namedWindow("Test OpenCV",1);


            while ( true ){
                capture >> frame;
                cv::imshow("Test OpenCV", frame );
                int key = cv::waitKey(1);
                if ( key == 27 )
                    break;
            }

        }

        void task2 (){
            int n = 0;
            while (1){
                cout<<"2nd thread "<<n<<"\n";
                sleep(3);
                n++;
            }
        }

        int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
            // insert code here...
            cout << "Hello, World!\n";
            thread t1(task1);
            thread t2(task2);
            //t1.join();
            //t2.join();
            int n = 0;
            while (1){
                cout<<"main thread "<<n<<"\n";
                sleep(1);
                n++;
            }  
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: It looks like that thread simply does not have a chance to run.

Comment: I had the same problem years ago with Qt and OpenCV. I am not sure but I think I took the C method: CvCapture* cvCaptureFromCAM(int device) and it worked.

Comment: @Ashalynd it runs for sure. i double-checked it with breakpoints and cout

Comment: Have you tried declaring `cap` as a global object?

Comment: When are you executing threads? The loop in main is infinite do-nothing. I also suggest you to not use thread to create capture object. You should create it in main and pass it to thread and use that thread to capture frames.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs as it should for me (without any modifications) and I get the live feed through the task1 thread (using OpenCV 2.4.5).
I added `-std=gnu++0x` flag for compiler support (otherwise g++ throws an error).

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x opencv_thread.cpp -o opencv_thread `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Check my console output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpJLj.png). I added a `cout << "1st thread "<< endl;` within the while loop in task1.

I think the issue might be specific to some opencv versions as I have seen similar issues in an older version (don't remember which one) and boost threads.
Can you give details about the version you used?. Also try it with 2.4.5.

Comment: I use linux and don't have osx :(. But my colleague advised me not to use 2.4.9 as it has similar issues (will confirm if it is the case with linux once I try it out). Can u try 2.4.5?

Comment: I've overcome this problem by reorganizing the project -> I put opencv logic in the main thread and the rest in the side ones :)

Anyway, I'll try 2.4.5 in couple days to check if it's opencv issue or something else.